# Cannot connect to newly created Azure VM

Tags: windows, azure, port, azure-virtual-machine, remote-desktop

I just created a new Azure virtual machine. I have gone into the `Azure portal` -> `Connect` -> `Download RDP File`. And then opened up the RDP file in Microsoft Remote Desktop.

I however get the error: `We couldn't connect to the remote PC. Make sure the PC is turned on and connected to the network, and that remote access is enabled.

The virtual machines `Networking` section also says: `Inbound traffic to the Public IP address may be blocked. You can update inbound port rules in the VM Networking page.`

I have tried the instructions [on here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal) but haven't had any luck...

Please see below for my current inbound and outbound port rules:

[image]

Comment: Could you show the NSG rule settings on your side? also, could you test `telnet vm 3389`? https://www.acronis.com/en-us/articles/telnet/

Comment: @NancyXiong you mean the inbound and outbound rules?

Comment: yes, you just need to add an inbound rule to open the RDP port 3389

Comment: @NancyXiong please see the image that I have attached

Comment: you need add the port 3389 for RDP

Comment: @NancyXiong Okay, when I click on `Add Inbound Port Rule` I get the options `Source`, `Source Port Ranges`, `Destinations`, `Destination Port Ranges`, `Priority`, `Name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you need to add the port 3389 for RDP traffic in the inbound security rule of NSG. Set the source with your local VM outbound PUBLIC IP or any. Destination port 3389. If you have a network interface level or subnet NSG, you have to add the rules to both of NSGs.

[image]

Comment: I've now done this. But I still get the connection error in MS Remote Desktop

Comment: Do I need to do the same for the Network Interface? (if that is even possible)

Comment: confused in your picture, If you have two NSGs, you should add it to both of NSGs.

Comment: Right right, is it a mistake that I have two NSGs? Should I typically have one only?

Comment: no right answer to that question. you might want to have 2 @pnizzle

Comment: You can leave a subnet level NSG so that every VM in this subnet could be taken effect. Nic level NSG works on a specific VM. You could optionally do this.

Comment: Okay, I will have to do some research on this stuff. Remote Desktop is now working by the way. Thank you